# MySQL Is This Code Needed?

Tags: mysql

I wrote some code a whie back and now I cam't remeber why I placed a line in.  Can anyone look at this and let me know if what this line does or if I even need it.  Memory is not what it use to be! It's this line.  `my_ulonglong numrows = mysql_num_rows(res_set);`

Heres the code....

```
(mysql_real_connect(conn,"gxxxx","gxxxx","gxxxx","gxxxx",0,NULL,0) !=0);
char queryString[1024];
sprintf(queryString, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblURLIP WHERE IP = '%s' AND IPStatus = '1' AND IPType = '3' AND IPMax ='0'",ipSrc == NULL ? "0" : ipSrc);
mysql_query(conn, queryString);
my_ulonglong i = 0;
res_set = mysql_store_result(conn);

// This is the questionable line
my_ulonglong numrows = mysql_num_rows(res_set);

LEGIT = mysql_fetch_row(res_set);
mysql_free_result(res_set);
    if (atoi(LEGIT[i]) == 1).....
```

Thank You

Comment: *You* wrote some code a while back and want *us* to tell what it does? Seriously? :)

Comment: It means...Comment your codes more! And dont share you database connection details!

Comment: btw, the access data you posted work... You should change your password

Comment: Hey Pekka. It was a seriously generic question. But I do catch your intent! LOL!!!!!!!!!! Very cool website!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a trick question? I ask because if you took a look at the MySQL docs you'd see right away that you need that line of code. After it executes, `numrows` holds the number of rows that MySQL returned to you when you called `mysql_store_result(conn)`.

Comment: Thank you. I was sure it was an operational question. Like I said. I'm not so sharp anymore!  Haven't used mySql ina awhile. You know what they say, If you dont use it, you lose it!